# Idiom for 'Resisting just to resist'

Tags: idiom-requests

Recently, I've been listening to the song 'Time and Time Again" by Chronic Future ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45TEYZp213E) for those who wish to listen).

Around line 6 of verse 3, the lyric is

> You dig yourself so deep you resist just to resist

I don't know if I'm just having a bout of deja vu, but I'm fairly sure that there is an idiom that refers to the concept of 'resisting just to resist', but I'm not sure if it really does exist or not. If it does exist and someone knows what it is, I request that you tell me, please. Or if it doesn't exist, let me know about that as well. Thanks!

Comment: Ornery, stubborn

Comment: I would say "childish".

Comment: I think the archetypal expression is 'arguing for argument's sake' or 'arguing for the sake of arguing'. You can look these up. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eristic) has **eristic** – pertaining to argument just for the sake of argument, rather than to establish what is the truth of the matter (OWTTE).

Comment: Being *contrary*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is

***...* for the sake of it**

As defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for%20the%20sake%20of%20it):

> *idiom* : for no particular reason

In your context, it could imply that the person "resisting just to resist" is resisting to the point where there is no reason for doing it; they are **resisting for the sake of resisting [it]**.